# Best Practice for Kaggle Datasets with Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I was wondering if anyone could confirm the best practice for downloading kaggle datasets to our colab notebooks?

I have seen code examples like the one below where we download the API token file and upload it to the environment, is that the best practice or is there a different/simpler/better approach?

Thanks in advance!
Jacob

```
from google.colab import files
!pip install -q kaggle
files.upload()
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle datasets download -d alxmamaev/flowers-recognition
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches that are both convenient:

1) Save your `kaggle.json` in GDrive. Then mount by just clicking (in the left pane). Then, copy it here.

```
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp "drive/My Drive/kaggle.json" ~/.kaggle/
# the rest is the same
```

2) Embed the `kaggle.json` in Colab itself.

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!echo '{"username":"korakot","key":"8db2xxx"}' > ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
# the rest is the same
```

If you are worried, use the first which is more secure.

If you are lazy, use the second.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!  I will give these a try!